# Messagebox.Show from a background application

Tags: c#

I have a application which runs on background and monitors iTunes running.Now the background application is in minimized state and there is a notify icon to show that the background application.
Every time some exception occurs in background application I want to display it to user.
I uses Messagebox.Show but the popped-up message is not displayed on top of the windows and is in minimized state.I can only see that in the task bar.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: How about you show some code? This might help enormously...

Comment: Why not use [balloon notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx) from your icon - you know, the way that otherwise invisible applications interact with users?

Comment: Not much code to show <br>MessageBox.Show(
                        Resources
                            .FrmPreferences_SetSongFromCloud_iTunes_is_taking_long_to_connect_to_cloud_Unable_to_set_last_media_from_cloud_,
                        ClsUtils.Finally, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

Comment: Why do you run your application in minimized-state? I would prefer to make the window invisible. The notify-Icon should be enough. If a error occures and you call MessageBox.Show(...) it should be in the foreground

Comment: Tomtom its not minimized .there is only notification icon to show the application.Every time i uses messagebox.show the message comes as minimized

Comment: If Messagebox doesn't work for you, use a custom form maybe?

Comment: Please don't do this. If anything, use balloon notifications. There is little that's more annoying than some app that decides its notifications are so important that it has to pop up over the top of whatever I'm working on.